# can I shrink coefficients to exactly 0 using BFGS?

Tags: r, algorithm, time-series

I am trying to implement an adaptive Lasso approach for GARCH MIDAS data. I am using the negative LLF in combination with the L1 penalty.

I get somewhat descent results using
`constrOptim(method = "BFGS")`

and the irrelevant varaibles become small but never zero.

I also tried to implement an gradient descent approach but that I cant really get to work.

```
        while(Norm(p_new-p,Inf)>1e-5){
      gradient <- num_grad_g(p,data)     
        gradient_step <- p - s*gradient
        prox_operator <- sign(gradient_step)*pmax(abs(gradient_step)-lambda,0)
        if(sum(prox_operator[c(2,3)]%>%abs(),.5*prox_operator[4])>=.99){
          prox_operator[c(2,3,4)]=prox_operator[c(2,3,4)]/sum(prox_operator[c(2,3,4)]%>%abs())
        }
        prox_operator[1]<-pmax(prox_operator[1],0.001)
        prox_operator[2]<-pmax(prox_operator[2],0.001)
        prox_operator[3]<-pmax(prox_operator[3],0.001)
        prox_operator[4]<-pmax(prox_operator[4],0.001)
          pnew<-prox_operator
          if(Norm(prox_operator-p,Inf)>1e-5){
            p=prox_operator
          }else break
        }
```